# How can I get user information from JWT tocken?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I'm react-native developer, I'm new to Magento, REST and OAuth. I want to use the Magento 2.0 OAuth REST API to login into my app
I am getting this token as shown in the image, how can I use this token to do login authentication in react native application?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The token is NOT encoded user-information. There is no way to extract information from it on the client side. The token is a key in a DB table (oauth_token) where you can look up  the customer_id tied to the token.

Or you make a second request (/customer/me) with that token to get all user info.

Comment: In Magento 2.4.4 data is not stored in oauth_token table